# Show that $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_9}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The problem is:

Construct the group table for the additive group $\mathbb{Z_3}$, and show that $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_9}$. \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
+& \overline0 & \overline1 & \overline2 \\ \hline \overline0  & & &\\ \hline \overline1  &  & &\\ \hline \overline2  &  & &\\ \hline  \end{array}

I was able to construct the table as 
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
+& \overline0 & \overline1 & \overline2 \\ \hline \overline0  &0 &1 &2\\ \hline \overline1  &1  &2 &0\\ \hline \overline2  &2  &0 &1\\ \hline  \end{array}
However, I'm having troubles showing that that $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_9}$. How can this be done?

Also, I'm not sure if I should overline the numbers in the table as well or I can keep them like this.

Comment: It would be consistent to overline them as given. So $\overline{1}$ consists of all integers $a\equiv 1\bmod 3$. What is $a$ modulo $9$? Try to make explicit examples, so $a=-2,1,4,7,10,\ldots $.

Comment: The problem is that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ isn't a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_9$, it's only isomorphic to one.

Comment: Of course once one allows isomorphisms there'e no problem. But if the OP constructs the addition table for $\mathbb{Z}_9=\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ using the overline convention, then there's the strong possibility of confusion about why $\overline{1}$ is being identified with $\overline{3}$. I don't think the question is a sensible one to set to beginners.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But $Z/3Z$ is not even a subset of $Z/9Z$ (where $Z := {\mathbb Z}$).

Comment: Right. This is a terribly formulated problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find an element $\alpha$ of order 3 in $\mathbb{Z}_9$. The subgroup generated by that element will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ via a group homomorphism which sends $\alpha\mapsto 1$ .

Answer (score 0):

This result is a consequence of the fact that $3$ is prime, $3\mid 9$, and [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).